# Delphi connection to OpenEdge Progress-4GL Database

Tags: database, delphi, odbc, progress-4gl, openedge

Folks:

Has anyone had success connecting to a **Progress-4GL** database with **Delphi**?   I've been unable to establish any connection with the ODBC driver provided by the vendor (*Progress OpenEdge 10.1C Driver*).  I've entered (what I believe are) the right parameters, but keep on getting an error whenever I test the connection:

```
   "[DataDirect][ODBC Progress OpenEdge Wire Protocol driver] Socket closed."
```

*Background:* I've been tasked to re-design a 13-year-old application, but the original programmer did not provide any supporting documents, passwords, configuration setup, etc. (I'm on my own)!    To make things worse, online help and useful documentation about Progress is scarce (I had never heard about this database until now).

I want to examine the existing data, maybe create an ERD to familiarize myself with the schema, but I can't even access the data outside of the OpenEdge code.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need help with Progress I suggest you enlist in one or more of the Progress mailing lists at [PEG](http://www.peg.com/).

Progress is a niche product, and didn't age well, or at least the technical decision taken (and defended) by Progress were abandoned by the rest of the industry, so some things you may take for granted will prove cumbersome or at least a bit alien.

Anyway, PEG is a great resource and the people in there are very knowledgeable and usually eager to help people working with Progress technology (or so they were when I used to subscribe, a few years ago).

Comment: What technical decisions did they take that were controversial? Flat file non-sql non-relational database technology?

Comment: SQL is basically an afterthought, does not play nicely with other techical stacks (.NET/J2EE/Perl/Python/Ruby/Whatever...), no views, no nested transactions, no distributed transactions, index use is decided at *compile* time instead of at runtime, compiler checks are not very strict (better with more recent versions), poor logging/debugging support, no foreign keys...

Comment: Wow. So basically all the core flaws of a proprietary 1980s non-relational database management system. And what if there were bugs in that giant mystery-implementation-runtime too. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I've seen that databasen when I was on college. We had some excerises with it and as far as I remember it was awful experience.

Maybe this [link](http://www.progresstalk.com/archive/index.php?f-39.html) will help. I whish I could help more, though.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  The link is a great starting point ... I looked at some of the items and feel I might find some answers.  
  
Again, I truly appreciate your help.

Comment: No problem Cesar, if you find a solution you could post it here. Who knows, maybe some of us will need such connection in the future...

Answer (score -2):

If there's still a need for help with Progress, I'm a contractor which specializes in the language and can help people with their Progress development or migration problems.